# Passing constant to C++ constructor

Tags: c++

I have a class where the constructor receives an integer:

```
class One
{
public:
    One(int i)
    {
        foo(i);
    }

    void foo(int i)
    {
        // Do something with i
    }
};
```

The above compiles fine.

I have a second class that has a member of type One. Compiling this results in an error where I pass the int (the error is "expected a type specifier"):

```
class Two
{
public:
    One x(1);
};
```

I can, however, initialize the member if it is a pointer:

```
class Three
{
public:
    One *x = new One(1);
};
```

Can I initialize the class without using a pointer?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could also try `One x = 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With:

```
class Two
{
public:
    One x(1);
};
```

and based on language rules, the compiler attempts to parse `x` as a member function returning an object of type `One`, but rather than seeing valid *parameter-declarations* which requires at least a list of 0 or more *type-specifier*s, it sees a *non-type*.

> ```
> class Three
> {
> public:
>     One *x = new One(1);
> };
> ```
>
> Can I initialize the class without using a pointer?

Yes, use the *uniform-brace-initialization* syntax for [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

```
class Three
{
public:
    One x{1};
};
```

Or [*copy-initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

```
class Three
{
public:
    One x = 1;  //Uses converting constructor, 
    //see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor

    //or
    One x = One(your, multiple, arguments, here);
};
```

Or [*member-initializer-lists*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#content) in the Constructor:

```
class Three
{
public:
    Three(...) : x(1) { ... }
    One x;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the braces (and "=" won't work because I actually have multiple arguments passed to the constructor).

Comment: @SteveA also read up on the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Answer (score 4):

```
One x(1);
```

is parsed as a function declaration, that is why it expects a type in parentheses. You can use

```
One x = 1;
```

or

```
One x{1};
```

instead.